# Axios GET call times out, however the same request with CURL works

Tags: docker, vue.js, flask, networking, timeout

Context:
The app is currently running on a docker container.
There are three containers in total, all of them attached to the same network.
-MariaDB
-Flask app
-Vue app (node-16-buster)

When trying to call an api from my flask backend I get this error from axios:
[image]

However, when I copy the url and just try curl (from the vue container's terminal) it works like a charm.
[image]
No such problems were observed when I ran everything on my local machine.

This is the app's vite.config.js file.

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server:{
    port: 80,
    host: "0.0.0.0"
  }
})
```

I tried fiddling with different docker network configurations, but those yielded no results.

Comment: You Axios call is made from the browser, right? That doesn't run in the vue app docker container...

Comment: Yes I open the app in a browser, but the app runs on the container and the call itself is made from the container

Comment: I'm pretty sure the call is made from your browser. That's why the error appears in your browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this indeed turns out to be correct. Since the code runs on the browser I just had to change the URL to be correct.
I.e. pointing to the host where the docker containers run, rather than pointing to the docker container iteself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).